# iPhone local notification still showing old message

Tags: objective-c

I am currently creating an application that uses local notification. Previously, I coded the message as XXXX, then a few weeks later, I coded the message to be YYYY. And now when I do a test run on my app. Sometimes I get the notification with message XXXX and sometimes I get it with the message YYYY. Anyone has an idea of what is causing the issue?

Comment: Does this local notification have a `repeatInterval`?

Comment: Yup, and that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Apparently, I still have old notifications which shows XXXX